# Defining variable type

Tags: c++, integer, max

ALL,

According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7fh3a000.aspx) the maximum integer value is unsigned long.

So if I have a value which is bigger the only way is to use double, right? Or there is another alternative?

Here is my code:

```
unsigned long id;
retcode = SQLPrepare( stmt, qry, SQL_NTS );
retcode = SQLExecute( stmt );
retcode = SQLFetch( stmt );
retcode = SQLGetData( stmt, 1, SQL_C_ULONG, &id, 0, &cbName );
```

(error handling omitted)

In here I am getting "Out of range" error on the last line execution. I presume it is because the id is too big to be stored inside the unsigned long.

Any idea how to solve this?

P.S.: I want to save 14757395258967641292, which is bigger even for `unsigned long long`

Comment: Use a better reference http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/climits

Answer (score 3):

There are several libraries out there for big integers. There is [Boost.Multiprecision](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html) and in that you would be interested in [Integer Types](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/ints.html). [This](https://www.google.com/search?q=big%20integer%20in%20c%2B%2B&oq=big%20integer&gs_l=psy-ab.3.3.0i10i67k1j0j0i10i67k1j0i67k1.259020.260699.0.267513.2.2.0.0.0.0.164.313.0j2.2.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.2.311.zM8RYUcrIXo) Google search will reveal all kinds.

Comment: I want to have as little dependency as possible, and so am trying to omit any. If there is no other alternatives - I will look at it. I also updated the question with some code to show where the issue is

Comment: From your update it looks like the issue is on the database side as well as the code side. And if unsigned long long works for you, good. I'm not that verse with SQL but it looks like if you use SQL_C_BINARY the server will not do conversions on your data and you can store it as a _BLOB_. Then you can store numbers as big as you would like. The only catch I can think of is if you share data between machines with different [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Answer (score 0):

You don't use double to store whole values, you can use long.

Comment: Integer values can be stored with perfect precision into `double` variables up to 2^53; in facts, it was the simplest way to deal with integers bigger than 2^32 on 32 bit compilers before `long long` and `int64_t` were standardized.

Comment: @KillerDeath, Question updated with the code for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the value in the DB is stored as a signed integer. And so changing the

```
retcode = SQLGetData( stmt, 1, SQL_C_ULONG, &id, 0, &cbName );
```

to

```
retcode = SQLGetData( stmt, 1, SQL_C_SLONG, &id, 0, &cbName );
```

fixed the issue.

Hopefully this will help someone else.

Sorry for the noise and thank you for reading.